# google-apps-script mobile alert

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to provide some kind of a message / alert / dialog when using the Google Apps Script for Sheets - these seem to work in the Desktop version but not when using the app on a mobile device.  Have tried searching for a solution, but no luck - any leads or creative ideas would be great.  The best I can think of so far would be to use a block of cells to provide instructions for the user, and then hide then cells once the action is taken.  But preferably would be some kind of pop-up.  Any kind of lead would be great.

Thanks in advance!
Adam

Answer (score 1):

You could use 3rd party notification services like Pushbullet. It won't provide a pop-up within the user's mobile browser or google's mobile sheets app. But the pushbullet app could be installed on the same mobile device and will receive notifications in the form of a note, image, url. etc.

You can easily use their REST API from google apps script to send a message to the mobile device. [pushbullet-API](https://docs.pushbullet.com/)